# Extract union member based on a member's attribute

Tags: typescript, types

Given:

```
type TheUnion = { kind: 'a', attr1: number } | { kind: 'b', attr2: string }
```

I wanna be able to extract one of these union members based on a `kind` value. Like so:

```
{ kind: 'a', attr1: number } == ExtractKind<TheUnion, 'a'>
```

Here's my failing attempt:

```
type ExtractKind<T extends { kind: string }, U extends T['kind']> = T['kind'] extends U ? T : never;
```

[A playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKgCygVQHYEsD2qYF4YDeMA1uqgCYBcMA5AIY0A0MdIIATgIzWoCuAtgCMo7GAF8YAH0IkyVWoKYs27AEzUAzhzIBzccFCRYANTrt0dVCDwwAogA8OdAMYgA0nIA8iFBmzN6GgA+A1DwaDtHdhd3LzgYKEcoCg0ZUgpNbVQ9MWZkBKSU+ABtGnTyGgBdIJtgGHqSsrkqgpBk8lT8gH54GB4oADcRAG5gIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type TheUnion = { kind: 'a', attr1: number } | { kind: 'b', attr2: string }

type ExtractKind<T extends { kind: string }, U extends T['kind']> =
    T extends { kind: U } ? T : never
//  ^ The conditional type is distributed over all union parts of T ("naked type parameter")

type TA = ExtractKind<TheUnion, 'a'> 
// = { kind: 'a', attr1: number } | never = { kind: "a"; attr1: number; } 
type TB = ExtractKind<TheUnion, 'b'> //  { kind: "b"; attr2: string; }
// = never | { kind: 'b', attr2: string } = { kind: 'b', attr2: string }
```

The built-in [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) type simplifies `ExtractKind` further:

```
type ExtractKind2<T extends { kind: string }, U extends T['kind']> = Extract<T, { kind: U }>
```

[Code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=17&pln=9&pc=20#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFhAqgOwJYHtlQLxQN5QDWqyAJgFxQDkAhlQDRQ3DABOAjJcgK4C2ARhFZQAvlAA++IiQrV+DJi1YAmSgGc2JAOaiAULtCQoAUQAebGgGNgAaRkAeGFAjmIZNVOJl1m5DpGMiM6u7rAA2lRepFQAugB8OLDBwG6kHgRRlEFiAPxJXBAAbkL6htAwAIKJZhbWdmSOCCgYyIy0VAkA9J1QZbBVuBkylABENCMA3IpsnFA8AkJTIgbg5QBC1easVrYO8EhomG3yXT2ew1Aj-JPTKj6s2kv6K0Y123Uyyo7JqenS3lANA8-KJAj9QjAIlFYglcG8do5GEMAdk4kA)

Comment: Nice! Could you please explain why `T extends { kind: U }` works, and `T['kind'] extends U` doesn't?

Comment: Sure, you only get this distributive property, if `T` appears alone at the top-level and is not part of some other type expression like `T['kind']`. If this is the case, `T` is called a "naked type parameter" (that's what the docs call it)

Comment: Or in other words, with your type in the question, `ExtractKind<TheUnion, 'a'>` would resolve to:  `TheUnion['kind'] extends "a" ? { kind: 'a', attr1: number } | { kind: 'b', attr2: string } : never`. And that would be  `"a" | "b" extends "a" ? ... : never`.   `"a" | "b"` can never be just `"a"`, so you get `never` back.

Comment: Ooooooooooh... THAT helped. Thanx! May I ask.. What resource helped you the most to get a nice intuitive understanding of the TS typesystem?

Comment: Oh boy, that is a tough question... Actually you learn a lot from the [TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) alone ,which is kept beginner friendly (ps: a more modern [new version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) is on its way). I also learned a lot by justing reading other SO posts here.